# Like operator in SQL Query in SQL Datasource

Tags: sql, asp.net, select, sqldatasource

I have to use like operator for SQL Command in SQL Datasource, but it is not working. Did some one run into the issue? Please Advise.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="gridSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>"
     SelectCommand=" select * from [test where domain like '%@DomainID%'">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="DomainID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ControlID="ddlcu"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @nameparam + '%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      where  Domain LIKE '%' + @DomainID + '%'" >
```

we need send this way in order to get the like operator work.Thanks